# HTML email show a text vertically centered to the image responsive

Tags: html, css, html-email

This is what i have currently developed. I would like the text to be right of the image and vertically center aligned with respect to the image in desktop view and to the bottom of the image in mobile view. You are free to change the entire html markup if required to achieve this.

NOTE the image is bigger than the text.

```html
<table class="col-2 mobile-full-width" style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td text-align="center" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;padding-top: 20px;text-align: center;padding-bottom: 0;vertical-align: center;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;vertical-align: center;">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
          <tr>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="220" style="width:220px;">
        <![endif]-->
        <table class="profile-label mobile-full-width" width="220px" style="width:220pt; float:left;" align="left">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="220">
                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1029/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg" width="500" height="310" border="0" style="display: block;" alt="">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              </td>
              <td  valign="middle" width="440" style="width:440px;">
        <![endif]-->
        <table class="profile-description mobile-full-width" width="440px" style="width:440px;height: 100%;vertical-align: center;" align="left">
          <tbody style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <tr>
              <td class="field-column" style="word-break: break-all;">
                some text that should be vertically center alligned
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **vertically center aligned to the image** ? Do you want the text to be displayed IN the middle the image ?

Comment: @JohnSaucisse No, the image should come outside the image to the right  &vertically centered wrt to the image.

Answer (score 2):

Change `height: 100%` to the height of the image. Try something like `height: 310px` to `.profile-description`

Change this..

`<table class="profile-description mobile-full-width" width="440px" style="width:440px;height: 100%;vertical-align: center;" align="left">`

To this.... 

`<table class="profile-description mobile-full-width" width="440px" style="width:440px;height: 310px;vertical-align: center;" align="left">`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. but the issue is if I do that in mobile view there will be lot of blank space on top & bottom of the text

Comment: Mind you, `width="440px"` should be `width="440"`. HTML attributes don't have units for pixels. Only if percentages =)

Comment: I'll upvote this question as it's the closest to the true answer. Stating the obvious, the blank space can be combatted with media queries. Generally, this design is inferior, truly modern emails don't use this design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use **vertical-align:middle**.

```css
div.container, div.img, div.text {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div.img {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
}

div.text {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">IMAGE HERE</div>
  <div class="text">
    Some text here !
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gmail does not support the display:inline-block style so both the divs come on two different lines

Comment: I don't like this answer, you can't just put `div`'s like that, you need nested table structure!

Comment: @revelt please explain why or provide some kind of documentation or reference.

Comment: @Kadriles answer is Outlook 2007-2016 and above, see https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, row which says "display". `display: inline-block` won't work there. This is elementary basics in email development — you have to use tables, only div's won't render fine consistently across all email software. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this that works in most of the popular email clients is to break the image into two. This is how i did it, might not be the best solution out there.

1. The part that should come above the sentence.
2. Rest of the image and the text next to it.